# how to get precise current location in a building map

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, gps, currentlocation

i have one **building map** and it have so many rooms on it.

Now i want to **drop the pin** in that building map, where the user is being in that building and also i want to draw the direction if user want to navigate to some other room.

if anyone knows please guide me in right way.

Comment: Accept your answers in future, otherwise you will find it difficult to get them.

Comment: How you have solved this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inhouse navigation (or navigation if no GPS signal is available) is often done using WLAN triangulation. You need to scan the WLANs in the building to build a map of field strength of the various WLAN signals for specific locations. During navigation the map is used to determine the most likely position for a given reading of WLAN signals.

E.g. Google is working on an inhouse navigation service and there are some companies offering inhouse navigation solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QRCode based pseudo-location. User scans QRCode in one room of the building and the app is aware of phone's location.