# Android mapping/gps query

Tags: android, gps, maps

A project I will hopefully be doing for my 4th year project is as follows (it's only an idea at the moment):
It will show your timetable (Day, time, class, room etc), but say one of your classes is in room IT101 but you don't know where that room is. You press on IT101 and it will show you a map of the IT building and highlight the room you want.

I'm a total beginner at doing apps, so I'm wondering is it possible to do that and if it is how hard would it be to do and how would I go about doing it?

I am also thinking that if the user has the gps enabled that I would be able to see where the user is and pinpoint that on the map (a kind of "A is where you are" and "B is where you need to be"), but I'm not sure how accurate gps can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do in-house navigation. This is difficult using GPS since you need a clear view of several GPS satellites, which you will not have in a building.

In-house navigation is often done using WLAN triangulation, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12176718/1127492

Comment: I guess the app would be used mostly in buildings, but it can also be used at home/outside the college.